# “Unrecognized selector sent to instance” in UIView class when calling addTarget

Tags: swift, class, uibutton, selector, swift5

I am trying to create a DropDownMenu class, but when I try to call addTarget to one of the buttons, this error comes up.

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd167f06120' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I would really appreciate any help and no answer is a bad one!

Here is my entire class

```
class DropDownMenu: UIView {
    // Main button or Pre
    var main: UIButton! = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 30))
    var view: UIView!
    
    
    // Title
    var buttonTitles: [String]! = [""]
    var titleColor: UIColor! = UIColor.black
    var font: UIFont! = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    // Individual Button
    var buttonsBorderWidth: CGFloat! = 0
    var buttonsBorderColor: UIColor? = UIColor.white
    var buttonsCornerRadius: CGFloat! = 0
    var color: UIColor! = UIColor.clear
    // Button Images
    var buttonsImageEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets? = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    var images: [UIImage]? = nil
    // Onclick stuff
    var target: UIViewController!
    
    private var currentSelected: String? = nil
    
    private var optionsStack = UIStackView()
    
    init(main: UIButton) {
        self.main = main
        super.init(frame: CGRect())
    }
    
    func createDropDownMenu() {
        main.addTarget(target, action: #selector(DropDownMenu.openDropdown(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        print("Button Target?: \(main.allTargets), self.target: \(String(describing: target))")
        
        let mainFrame = main.frame
        
        optionsStack.frame = CGRect(x: mainFrame.minX, y: mainFrame.maxY, width: mainFrame.width, height: CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * mainFrame.height)
        optionsStack.axis = .vertical
        
        view.addSubview(optionsStack)
                
        var y: CGFloat! = 0
        
        for title in buttonTitles {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: mainFrame.width, height: mainFrame.height))
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(titleColor, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = color
            button.titleLabel?.font = font
            button.addTarget(target, action: #selector(DropDownMenu.onclick), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            y += mainFrame.height
            
            optionsStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
        
        for button in optionsStack.arrangedSubviews {
            button.isHidden = true
            button.alpha = 0
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func openDropdown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
        optionsStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { (button) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7) {
                button.isHidden = !button.isHidden
                button.alpha = button.alpha == 0 ? 1 : 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func onclick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let title = sender.titleLabel!.text
        
        print(title as Any)
        
        main.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        
        optionsStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { (button) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7) {
                button.isHidden = true
                button.alpha = 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is the code and creation of the object in ViewController

```
let grade = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 80, height: 30))
grade.layer.borderWidth = 1
grade.setTitle("Grade", for: .normal)
grade.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
grade.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        
let gradeDP = DropDownMenu(main: main)
gradeDP.buttonTitles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]
gradeDP.color = UIColor.gray
gradeDP.target = self
gradeDP.titleColor = UIColor.white
gradeDP.view = view

view.addSubview(grade)
gradeDP.createDropDownMenu()
```

The first print statement in the createDropDownMenu() function prints...

> Button Target?: [AnyHashable(<HomeworkHelp.DropDownMenu: 0x7ffb555200b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002bdf5c0>>)], self.target: Optional(<HomeworkHelp.CreateAccountViewController: 0x7ffb5550a7b0>)

After editing it with the help of mightknow I came up with this class. It doesn't have any onclick actions for the mainButton in it.

```
class DropDownMenu: UIStackView {
    
    var options: [String]! = [] // Labels for all of the options
    var titleButton: UIButton! = UIButton() // The Main Title Button
    
    init(options: [String]) {
        self.options = options
        let mainFrame = titleButton.frame
        
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: mainFrame.minX, y: mainFrame.maxY, width: mainFrame.width, height: mainFrame.height * CGFloat(options.count)))
        
        var y: CGFloat = 0
        for title in self.options {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.frame.width, height: mainFrame.height))
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(titleButton.titleLabel?.textColor, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = titleButton.backgroundColor
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dropDownOptionClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            button.isHidden = true
            button.alpha = 0
            
            self.addArrangedSubview(button)
            
            y += 1
        }
    }
    
    @objc func openDropDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Open DropDownMenu")
        for button in self.arrangedSubviews {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7) {
                button.isHidden = !button.isHidden
                button.alpha = button.alpha == 0 ? 1 : 0
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func dropDownOptionClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.titleLabel?.text as Any)
    }
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And than my ViewController is ...

```
let dp = DropDownMenu(options: ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"])
        
let titleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 180, height: 40))
titleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
titleButton.setTitle("DropDownMenu", for: .normal)
titleButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
titleButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
titleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dp.openDropDown(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
dp.titleButton = titleButton
```

The error ...

> Button Target?: [AnyHashable(<HomeworkHelp.DropDownMenu: 0x7ffb555200b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002bdf5c0>>)], self.target: Optional(<HomeworkHelp.CreateAccountViewController: 0x7ffb5550a7b0>)

still comes up and I am clueless as to why.

Comment: view.addSubview(main), maybe you missed it?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response! I did add it to my view though, so that isn't the problem

Comment: can you try self.openDropDown instead of DropDownMenu.openDropDown

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I also tried doing the addTarget in ViewController. That also caused the same error.

Comment: Where are you calling `createDropDownMenu`?

Comment: Did y9ou set `target` to your `viewController` before calling `createDropDownMenu`?

Comment: I called createDropDownMenu() many lines below when adding everything to their respective subviews. I did set the target before I called the function

Comment: I found something interesting... openDropdown() in the class gets called even when I don't press the button. Also, when I print 'self.openDropdown(main)' inside of the class it prints '()'. I call the function and pass in main as the sender and it prints '()'. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The 'error' is not an error. It looks like the result of one of your print() statements. Does the code work otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The target has to be the DropDownMenu.

```
titleButton.addTarget(dp, action: #selector(dp.openDropDown(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Here is the rest of the code...

```
let titleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 290, width: 100, height: 40))
titleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
titleButton.setTitle("Grade", for: .normal)
titleButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
titleButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
titleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
let dp = DropDownMenu(options: ["1", "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "Senior", "College"])
dp.titleButton = titleButton
dp.target = self
dp.borderWidth = 2
dp.spacing = 5
dp.cornerRadius = 10
dp.bgColor = UIColor.white
```

Adding it to subviews and creating it...

```
view.addSubview(titleButton)
view.addSubview(dp)
dp.createDropDownMenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the target as a `UIViewController` when the method you're calling is actually a method of the `DropDownMenu` class. What you need to do is set the target to `self` instead of the `target` property:

```
main.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DropDownMenu.openDropdown(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, here is the code I'm using to test it. There are some layout/color choices I made just to make it clear to me, but this works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let main = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 80, height: 30))
    main.layer.borderWidth = 1
    main.setTitle("Grade", for: .normal)
    main.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    main.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            
    let gradeDP = DropDownMenu(main: main)
    gradeDP.buttonTitles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]
    gradeDP.color = UIColor.gray
    gradeDP.target = self
    gradeDP.titleColor = UIColor.white
    gradeDP.view = UIView()
    
    self.view.addSubview(gradeDP)
    let b = self.view.bounds
    gradeDP.frame = CGRect(x: b.minX, y: b.minY, width: b.width, height: b.height/2)
    gradeDP.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    gradeDP.target = self
    gradeDP.addSubview(gradeDP.main)
    gradeDP.createDropDownMenu()
}}
```

As for your code, I'm going on the assumption that the code you added in the second part of your question is inside your ViewController's `viewDidLoad()` method, and that the `main` variable you're using to initialize your `DropDownMenu` is an instance variable of your ViewController, because I'm not seeing it anywhere else in scope. If that's the case, there are definitely some issues. They are:

1. You never actually add `gradeDP` to your view hierarchy. If that's what the line `gradeDP.view = view` is supposed to do, it's not. What that code actually does is set the `view` property of `gradeDP` to be a reference to the ViewController's `view` property. And, unless there is code in your DropDownMenu class that you haven't included, you're not actually using that reference for anything. So, you can get rid of that line entirely, and the `view` property in your `DropDownMenu` class. If what you're trying to do is set the ViewController's view to be `gradeDP`, that code would be `self.view = gradeDP`, but I don't actually recommend doing it that way. A `UIViewController`'s `view` property is used in some special functionality and probably shouldn't be messed with much. You probably want to add `gradeDP` as a subview, like I did in my code above.
2. The `grade` button you created is not used by your DropDownMenu. I'm guessing you meant to initialize with that instead of the `main` variable (that is out of scope of your code), like this:

   `let gradeDP = DropDownMenu(main: grade)`

In short, unless there is code elsewhere that you haven't shared, what your code above does is create a UIButton labeled "Grade" that is visible but doesn't actually do anything (and isn't part of your DropDownMenu), and a DropDownMenu that isn't actually visible, but would have a `main` button that calls `openDropdown(_:)` if it was. I'm guessing that's not how it's supposed to work. Hopefully the code I provided above helps get you where you want to be, though.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! Doing this removes the error, but openDropdown() doesn't get called.

Comment: You sure? That's a separate issue, then. It's working perfectly in the project I created to test it. I did a little bit of setup in my ViewController to make all that happen, though. Could be we did something different there.

Comment: Thank you for going through all of the effort to help me! So, the code you see is all of my code. The line "main.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DropDownMenu.openDropdown(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)" is inside of the class. I didn't create it in my ViewController.

Comment: OK. I'm going to edit my answer to post the ViewController code I used to get it to work. I think you have some issues with your view hierarchy. Also, I think you may want to consider putting as much of the setup code as possible inside the initializer for your DropDownMenu class instead of in the ViewController. That'll encapsulate the functionality a bit better, which will make it less error-prone and re-usable on multiple ViewControllers.

Comment: That would be really helpful! I am not sure what else I can change inside. Everything in the ViewController is just customizable options.

Comment: Where in your ViewController is that code? In viewDidLoad()? Also, where is the 'main' variable you're using to initialize your 'gradeDP'? Is that an instance variable of your ViewController? Because I'm not seeing it anywhere in scope.

Comment: So I have it in a function that is called first thing in viewDidLoad(), main is the var at the top of the DropDownMenu class. the line "let gradeDP = DropDownMenu(main: main)" is a typo that is fine in my code. It should be grade. The DropDownMenu main button (a.k.a grade) shows up, but when it is clicked it doesn't open the dropdown menu, or even call the function. The var view is needed to add it to that specific subview. view is actually not a UIViewContoller.view, it is the view that contains the dropdown menu.

Comment: The lines after "let b = ..." are not needed. The frame is gotten without the init(), You do not need to add the dropdown menu to the view. That is what the 10th line in the createDropDown function does. Adding gradeDP.main as a subview of gradeDP doesn't make too much sense. I am not sure as to why the function never calls on the click.

Comment: Getting your function to call is a separate issue which has nothing to do with your initial question about the error, so I didn't pay close attention to some of the inner code. Upon closer inspection, there are issues there that are causing your second problem (function not calling). I could help you with that too, but I've already taken time solving one problem without the answer being accepted or getting an upvote anywhere. My code above does already contain some breadcrumbs, though. Try it as is. It might not fit in your app like that, but the dropdown and functionality works.

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to upvote. I did put the checkmark though. I really need help getting the function to call. Do you know why is won't call.

Comment: Yes. I’m not at home right now and can’t walk you all the way through it, but there are problems with how you built your class. In the meantime if you want to use the view debugger I think it will show you that your views aren’t stacking the way you expect them to.

Comment: I am new to making classes so that is something that I expected. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: OK, there's quite a lot I can comment on, and honestly, it's probably best if you just kind of start over. You can keep a lot of your code, but most of it is in kinda the 'wrong' place. So, the first and most important thing is that when you're subclassing a UIView, it's because you're going to use it like a UIView, which is not what you're doing. The `view` property you're giving your DropDownMenu is unnecessary. You don't need a `view` property because your class IS the view, and you should treat it as such. So, you use it by putting in the ViewController `view.addSubview(<class instance>)`

Comment: The reason why I said to use the View Debugger is because with your code there isn't actually any DropDownMenu instance that gets added to the view hierarchy. It exists in memory, but it's not visible anywhere. Your "grade" button is visible because you added that as a subview of the ViewController's view, but it doesn't do anything because the way in which it is set up does not enable it to be the first responder. So, while you're rebuilding, a few things to keep in mind:

Comment: 1. The DropDownMenu is a UIView, just with extended custom functionality. So, when you want to make it visible in the ViewController you will add an instance of DropDownMenu as a subview of the ViewController's `view` property. All other views used to make it work like you want it should be subviews of DropDownMenu, and need not (and probably should not) be referenced at all in ViewController code. Which brings up the second point:

Comment: 2. When building classes, try to use the concept of Encapsulation. Meaning, amongst other things, that your class was created for a certain functionality, and you should try to separate that functionality from any other objects as much as possible. So, in this case, the DropDownMenu should know as little as possible about the ViewController, and vice versa. There are many reasons for this, but a few of the main ones are that it makes your code much less error-prone, easier to debug, easier to understand what's going on, and easier to update if you later want to add new features or whatnot.

Comment: So, the way to achieve this is to think about what information your class needs from outside of itself in order to be properly instantiated. Then, implement that when you're creating the instance(s) of the class, and leave everything else to the internal workings of the class. Specific to your example, the code in your ViewController where you create you DropDownMenu instance should be much simpler, and contain really only two things: 1. Initialization (which may include passing the names) and 2. sizing and positioning of the base view (DropDownMenu) only.

Comment: Code for the first part might look like this: `let dropdown = DropDownMenu(titles: ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"])`

Comment: Code for the second part (size and positioning) depends on exactly how you want that to appear, and can be done in multiple ways. However, what's key here is that what you're laying out is the `dropdown` variable from the comment above. It could be as simple as setting the frame, but realistically you may want to add constraints so it adapts to different screen sizes and orientations.

Answer (score 1):

As for suggestions with rebuilding your class so it works properly, you may want to start with something like this:

```
class DropDownMenu : UIView {

var dropdownOptions : [String] = []
private var titleButton : UIButton = UIButton()
private var optionsStack : UIStackView = UIStackView()
private var optionsButtons : [UIButton] = []

@objc private func openDropdown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Add code to make dropdown options appear. There are multiple ways of doing this. For instance, the optionsButtons could be hidden and then unhidden when it's clicked, or they could be created only once the button is clicked.
}

@objc private func selectedOption(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Code here for when option is selected
}

init(options: [String]) {
    self.dropdownOptions = options
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    // Customize all of your subviews here, and add them to your DropDownMenu (as subviews)
    // Add openDropdown(_:) target to self.titleButton
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
}
```

A lot of the code you have already written for your original version of the class can go inside the functions there. Also, there is a lot of unnecessary code in your original version. For example, the `target` variable is unused once you fixed the original error issue, the `view` variable is obsolete, and the `createDropDownMenu()` function is unnecessary because all of that code can go either in the init(options:) or openDropdown(_:) functions.

Then, if you choose to build out a class using that template, you would implement it in your ViewController's `viewDidLoad()` method with the code:

```
let dropdown = DropDownMenu(titles: ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"])
self.view.addSubview(dropdown)
// Follow that with layout code that ensures it's the proper size and in the proper location
```

I hope that combined with my comments make sense, are helpful, and aren't too overwhelming. What I recommend doing is starting a new empty project (or target) and building your class and adding it to a ViewController with nothing else in it. That's a good way to isolate it and check and make sure everything looks and works right. In case you want an alternate suggestion with how to build your class, you can actually try making DropDownMenu be a subclass of `UIStackView` (instead of `UIView`) with the main button and all option buttons being arranged subviews. This might actually be simpler, because it kind of cuts out the middleman, if you will, and all you'd need to do when opening/closing the dropdown is add/remove views from the `.arrangedSubviews` property.

Also important is that if your view needs to pass information (such as which option is selected) back to the ViewController, make sure the reference to the ViewController is marked `weak` so you don't create a retain cycle.

On a final note, if you're disappointed that there isn't a quick fix to get the original class to work and want to keep trying at that, there *might* be some way to cobble together a solution (like the code from my first answer, which does actually work...), but ultimately it will probably only cause more issues further down the line. So, best of luck with everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used your template, but changed it a little bit. I made it so that the subclass is UIStackView. I also remove all instances of the main button in terms of button actions. I put my updated code in the initial question so that you can view it in more detail.